# Calling RPG procedure from C++

Tags: c++, rpgle

I am busy with a C++ project on IBM i and is trying to call an RPG procedure that is in a service program, but I am not sure how to do that.

I only find examples on the internet and the [documentation](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzarh/sc092712.pdf) that shows how to call an RPG program (*PGM) object by defining it as follows:

```
extern "OS"
{
    void RPGPROGRAM(void);
}

int main()
{
    RPGPROGRAM();
    return 0;
}
```

The documentation says they are calling an RPG "procedure" but if you look at the actual source it is just a RPG program (*PGM) object that they call from within C++ using `#pragma map`.

Lets say I have the following RPG service program (lets name it RPGSP) with a procedure named `rpg_doSomething` defined in it:

```
ctl-opt nomain;

dcl-proc rpg_doSomething export;
  dcl-pi *n int(10);
    dcl-parm p_test char(20);
  end-pi;

  p_test = "It Works!!";

  return 1;

end-proc;
```

How should I declare and call the above procedure in my C++ program?

I have tried declaring it within the `extern` block but it ends up looking for the `rpg_doSomething` object at runtime and cannot find it. I have also tried binding the service program to the C++ program when compiling but that does not work either.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: With a mixed-case proc name, you'll probably want to add EXTPROC(*DCLCASE) to the dcl-pi spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off which C++ compiler are you using?

The native ILE one?  Then it should be pretty easy.  Pretty sure you just need:
`extern "RPG"` on the function declaration.

Or the AIX on in PASE? Then take a look at [Calling ILE procedures](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzalf/rzalfcallile.htm)

One thing to note, RPGLE is case insensitive and by default, uppercases names.  While C/C++ is case sensitive.  Your C++ program needs to be calling `RPG_DOSOMETHING`  or you need to apply a case sensitive name to the RPG procedure using `EXTPROC('rpg_DoSomething')`

Comment: And yes, I am using the ILE compiler, it was basically the case sensitivity and the `extern "RPG"` that solved it - so easy!